# What is the best way to browse a large font collection?

Tags: fonts, font-management

I needed one font...then i found 24000. I installed all of them. My computer started to take minutes to do everything. So ...

How do i browse all fonts without crashing everything..not that i think its a good idea.

Comment: It sounds like you downloaded some big free font package. Gotta say that I'm not a big fan of font packages, unless I can be certain that they are all _free_ to use commercially. Just saying.

Comment: Yea its kind useless after browsing through them they all start to look the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what OS you're on. I have nothing to offer for Windows but...

**For OS X**

[Font Explorer X](http://www.fontexplorerx.com/) is a fantastic app. If you're running an older OS (10.6, I believe) you can still use the old free version, if you can find it somewhere. The new paid one is excellent though.

If you just want to see what the fonts look like without any special software, OS X's quick view feature will do the trick (I'm sure Windows has something similar).

1. Go to your directory of fonts
2. Select the first item in the list
3. Hit the spacebar to bring up a preview
4. use the up and down arrows to move through the directory

Comment: i am on windows and yes i can double click but clicking on so many ones to find the right one is kinda very boring. It'd be better if it could show my text into all those fonts quickly.

Comment: With a decent font manager you can print specimen sheets for every font in your library. Many allow you to specify the text you want to use, up to a point.

Comment: More importantly, there really aren't that many fonts you *need* to use. Windows comes pre-installed with an excellent set of faces these days: Calibri, Cambria, Candara, Constantia, Corbel, even Gabriola if you want something fancy. Just stay away from things like Arial, Impact, and Comic Sans and you'll be okay ;)

Comment: lol---thanks...i really like open sans, helevtica, etc...and sometimes i need fancy ones for posters.